# What is the difference between `x instanceof Function` and `typeof x === 'function`

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-typescript

I want to create this hook in React (ts)

```
import { useState, useDeferredValue, useEffect } from "react";

type InitialValue<T> = T | (() => T);

function getStoredValue<T>(key: string, initialValue: InitialValue<T>) {
  const savedValue = localStorage.getItem(key);
  if (savedValue) return JSON.parse(savedValue) as T;
  // return initialValue instanceof Function ? initialValue() : initialValue;
  return typeof initialValue === "function" ? initialValue() : initialValue;
}

export default function useLocalStorage<T>(key: string, _default_value: InitialValue<T>) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(() => getStoredValue(key, _default_value));

  const deferredValue = useDeferredValue(value);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (deferredValue) localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(deferredValue));
    console.log("saved");
  }, [deferredValue]);

  return [value, setValue] as const;
}
```

how can i check for the type of `initialValue` in `getStoredValue` function

if i use `initialValue instanceof Function` it works

but if i use `typeof initialValue === "function"` i get this red-underline under `initialValue()` that says:

```
This expression is not callable.
  Not all constituents of type '(() => T) | (T & Function)' are callable.
    Type 'T & Function' has no call signatures.ts(2349)
```

i think to use typeof is better but why i get such a message from typescript

Comment: Just FWIW, in JavaScript, it's entirely possible for `typeof x === "function"` to be true but `x instanceof Function` to be false. It can happen with *host-provided* functions. Modern hosts don't tend to do that, but... (Another way is: `function x() { }; Object.setPrototypeOf(x, null);` but ... don't do that. :-D )

Comment: i want to create this hook and i get this message if i use typeof to check for type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual thing is indeed `typeof ___ === "function"`. I think the problem is that `T` is completely unconstrained, which means that `InitialValue` can be instantiated with `T` being a *function* (which is why we see `(() => T) | (T & Function)` in the error message).

If you update `InitialValue` to expect that `T` will not be a function, your `typeof initialValue === "function"` check works as you expect:

```typescript
type InitialValue<T> = T extends Function ? never : T | (() => T);
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVwM4FMDKMCGN0A0KGAIugGbpRToAmAajgDbKHHoCi5lAxvAL5xyUCCDgAiGjj7iA3AFgAUEpgBPMOjgBJAHbAYwZoxboAPABUAfHAC8cc3HQAPfDtqo4AMWQ6+wCDpwAPxwOugAblRwAFz2cAA+cAAUSQCUttbmqQrKiuQ+fgFwAOboMNjQdMasFpZJANboqrGoMFDAOsVEHfqGTNXosbq9Rsw1VukISnAzcDwBrXCoOJEMY5p2TBA8zBVQOKUAdKUwWvggDU3Z07PA5MnLqwOTN7OzNDDIUIEAUpgA8gA5Q5gHBQDBJR5VdbpHAecw5N78V5wD5fQJqDQQe49AyjEy2Gx2cT5XwGALiYJwXF9AZpGLUvR4-rrHLI3LOSCwOC0Cg4ZBMeCkwqBNDoAAy212MGgBzMVkuzSWbQ6XTgAH1eeR+YL1eF1kMmbT1rUXoo3vMdIsANr6kxEDAwAYAXVs7GweHQKXSNmsJz20JMiqImr5Apgeph11yFoW8C1VBoawJdjFZEo1EDrCSdtY0ZRYq4vBg3oyiBRbzuyQTmeTefL5reTZmWx2TD2csOjrO6AujVURD+QK7Ks6d1USRrSee0ebM3Zc7mCwgTHQhy2xSS4ihtHEs9m-CI1qnWfQzvzjZmaO+cFt6wdZRdcDhS6tMDZQA)